# Is reading from an anonymous pipe atomic, in the sense of atomic content?

Tags: c++, c, linux, multithreading, posix

I am writing a process on Linux with two threads. They communicate using an anonymous pipe, created with the `pipe()` call.

One end is copying a C structure into the pipe:

```
struct EventStruct e;
[...]
ssize_t n = write(pipefd[1], &e, sizeof(e));
```

The other end reads it from the pipe:

```
struct EventStruct e;
ssize_t n = read(pipefd[0], &e, sizeof(e));
if(n != -1 && n != 0 && n < sizeof(e))
{
    // Is a partial read possible here??
}
```

Can partial reads occur with the anonymous pipe?

The man page (`man 7 pipe`) stipulates that any write under PIPE_BUF size is atomic. But what they mean is atomic regarding other *writers* threads... I am not concerned with multiple writers issues. I have only one writer thread, and only one reader thread.

As a side note, my structure is 56 bytes long. Well below the PIPE_BUF size, which is at least 4096 bytes on Linux. It looks like it's even higher on most recent kernel.

Told otherwise: on the reading end, do I have to deal with partial read and store them meanwhile I receive a full structure instance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as you are dealing with fixed size units, there isn't a problem.  If you write a unit of N bytes on the pipe and the reader requests a unit of N bytes from the pipe, then there will be no issue.  If you can't read all the data in one fell swoop (you don't know the size until after you've read its length, for example), then life gets trickier.  However, as shown, you should be fine.

That said, you should still detect short reads.  There's a catastrophe pending if you get a short read but assume it is full length.  However, you should not expect to detect short reads — code coverage will be a problem.  I'd simply test `n < (ssize_t)sizeof(e)` and anything detected is an error or EOF.  Note the cast; otherwise, the signed value will be converted to unsigned and `-1` won't be spotted properly.

For specification, you'll need to read the POSIX specifications for:

- [`read()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html)
- [`write()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html)
- [`pipe()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html)

and possibly trace links from those pages.  For example, for `write()`, the specification says:

> Write requests to a pipe or FIFO shall be handled in the same way as a regular file with the following exceptions:
>
> - There is no file offset associated with a pipe, hence each write request shall append to the end of the pipe.
> - Write requests of {PIPE_BUF} bytes or less shall not be interleaved with data from other processes doing writes on the same pipe. Writes of greater than {PIPE_BUF} bytes may have data interleaved, on arbitrary boundaries, with writes by other processes, whether or not the O_NONBLOCK flag of the file status flags is set.

Or from the specification of `read()`:

> Upon successful completion, where `nbyte` is greater than 0, `read()` shall mark for update the last data access timestamp of the file, and shall return the number of bytes read. This number shall never be greater than `nbyte`. The value returned may be less than `nbyte` if the number of bytes left in the file is less than `nbyte`, if the read() request was interrupted by a signal, or if the file is a pipe or FIFO or special file and has fewer than `nbyte` bytes immediately available for reading. For example, a `read()` from a file associated with a terminal may return one typed line of data.

So, the `write()` will write atomic units; the `read()` will only read atomic units because that's what was written.  There won't be a problem, which is what I said at the start.

Comment: By any chance, do you have some resource to confirm your statement? :-)

Comment: POSIX specification and inference.  Reads and writes under PIPE_BUF are atomic.  If you only write a fixed size, and you only read the same fixed size, then you can only get units of that fixed size.  You can poke around the POSIX specifications: [`read()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html),
[`write()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html),
[`pipe()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html).  And to links from those pages.